# Unsupported operand type error when trying to multiply function parameter by an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm trying to make a simple function that takes an argument and multiplies it by an integer to return it multiple times. I attempted to do so with python 3 code that looks like this:

```
def user_input(x):
    print(x)


def repeat(y):
    return 5*y


repeat(user_input(input('Get input ')))
```

This code is supposed to take the argument `y`, in this case, the `user_input` function and multiply it by 5 so it should repeat 5 times. But whenever I run the program I get the following error:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'`
This error occurs in `return 5*y` and I understand that for some reason it interprets `y` as a `None` type. How would I have it interpreted as the appropriate type?

Comment: Nowhere did you have it run repeat? I do not understand.

Comment: @CATboardBETA in ```repeat()``` it just takes the user input function and is supposed to return it 5 times, which is why I multiplied it 5 times. Please tell me if there's a better way to do this. Edit: It is not supposed to keep asking for user input, it takes the information already inputted and returns it 5 times.

Comment: Your `user_input` function is not returning anything meaning it returns `None` and you are passing that to `repeat`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I tried adding ```return print(x)``` in  ```user_input```, same error. But ```user_input``` isn't supposed to return anything, it just takes whatever is inputted. ```repeat()``` is supposed to to return something

Comment: Try`return x` in `user_input`

Comment: And what is the return value of `print`? `None` again. You are passing the result of `user_input` to `repeat` so it needs to return something.

Comment: @anurag still shows the same error

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat but even with return it still shows the same error. This means that the value of ```user_input``` is still none.

Comment: @Thisbitchstoopid what did you write in the functions `user_input` ? the last line was supposed to be `return x`. Also, what are you entering at the prompt when asked for input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In programming languages, there are 2 things that we use functions for:
**Their side affects**
This includes things like:

- printing to the screen
- changing the value of a variable

**Their return value**
This is the value that functions "return" (just like mathematical functions).

## Your problem

You have a function that has a side affect (printing to the screen), but no return value. If a function doesn't explicitly return anything, then python returns the value "None".

## Solution

If you want to use the value from your first function as an argument with the second you could do something like this:

```
def user_input(x):
    return x

def repeat(x):
    return x*5

print(repeat(user_input("this is some user input")))
```

This will print out the *return* value of repeat, which is taking in the *return* value of user input, which is taking in a string.

### Clean Up

As a side note, the user input function does nothing now, it simply returns the value that it is passed, so you can do the following:

```
def repeat(x):
    return x*5

print(repeat(input(">>> ")))
```